# How to add new Div to particular element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                         $(document).ready(function(){
                             $('a#extra').click(function(event){
                                if($(this).attr('class') == 'extra'){
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    $(this).append('<div style="float:left;color:red;margin-left:10px;">Please Login/Register to view Details</div>').slideToggle(1000);

                                }
                             });
                         });
                     </script>
```

I have this jquery for adding div according to class in anchor attribute.

```
<a href="" class="extra_1" id="extra"></a>
<a href="" class="extra_2"  id="extra"></a>
<a href="" class="extra_3"  id="extra"></a>
```

i can check for class like the code shown above, but how can i check for extra_1, extra_2, extra_3, like if element with extra_1  class is clicked then add  to that element

Comment: Where is the element with ID of `extra`? Where variables should be added?

Comment: i have edited question now, as it should look like, please respond

Comment: Add a common class to each link, it can also be called 'extra'. So you would have class="extra_1 extra" and class="extra_2 extra" etc.

Comment: i have done as you said Endy , but now if($(this).attr('class') == 'extra') this does not works., please help

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your JQuery selector from a#extra to .extra. # is used for ID in selectors.

Comment: i have edited question as it should look like, please respond

Answer (score 1):

You use a wrong selector. Use 'a.extra' instead of 'a#extra'. If you use that selector, you don't need to check for that class inside the callback function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('a.extra').click(function(event){                               
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).append('<div style="float:left;color:red;margin-left:10px;">Please Login/Register to view Details</div>').slideToggle(1000);
        });
});
```

Comment: i have id also equal to extra but i have like 10 elements then id would become extra_1, extra_2 ...extra_10, now how can i match id like

Answer (score 0):

IDs must be *unique* your selector only selects the first element with ID of extra.

```
<a href="" class="extra_1 extra"></a>
<a href="" class="extra_2 extra"></a>
<a href="" class="extra_3 extra"></a>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.extra').click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         $(this).append('<div style="float:left;color:red;margin-left:10px;">Please Login/Register to view Details</div>').slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```