# selecting element using jquery & adding dynamically new element according to selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code to select the element & adding dynamically  if particular class is matched to current element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                         $(document).ready(function(){
                              $('a#extra').click(function(event){
                                 // alert($(this).attr('class'));
                                if($(this).attr('class') == 'extra'){
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    $(this).append('<div style="float:left;color:red;margin-left:10px;font:20px;margin: 3px 0 0 10px;">Please Login/Register to view Details</div>').slideToggle(5000);
                                    window.location.href='http://weddingsinwinnipeg.ca/signin/';
                                }
                             });
                         });
                     </script>

<a href="" class="extra extra_120" id="extra"></a>
<a href="" class="extra extra_145" id="extra"></a>
<a href="" class="extra extra_156" id="extra"></a>
```

i want to add  to anchor element on which i clicked, but above code does not works, please help

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add new Div to particular element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12172329/how-to-add-new-div-to-particular-element)

Comment: i didnt get solution to problem , i want to write clearly it another way, hope this this way helps, i will delete previously posted Question soon.

Comment: _Your solution is_: Use different IDs, IDs MUST BE UNIQUE.

Comment: what would be selector for that case instead of above mentioned selector

Answer (score 0):

Use `.hasClass` instead,

`$(this).attr('class')` will return the whole class attribute like `"extra extra_120"`.

Change

```
 if($(this).attr('class') == 'extra'){
```

to

```
 if($(this).hasClass('extra')){
```

***Update:***

Didn't notice you use same ids, instead of same ids, just use class will be ok.
And one more problem, you should redirect the page in the callback of `.slideDown`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a.extra').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).append('<div style="float:left;color:red;margin-left:10px;font:20px;margin: 3px 0 0 10px;">Please Login/Register to view Details</div>').slideToggle(5000, function () {
            window.location.href = 'http://weddingsinwinnipeg.ca/signin/';
        });
    });
});
</script>

<a href="" class="extra extra_120"></a>
<a href="" class="extra extra_145"></a>
<a href="" class="extra extra_156"></a>
```

Comment: doing this adds multiple <div> with same text ,it does add <div> for every anchor present on the page to current element, but i want to add only one time.

Comment: this class extra comes dynamically, if user is not login, i need to check the extra class that is a must, but the problem is that the code adds the number of <div> to single element , NUmber equals to number of <a> present with class extra

Answer (score 0):

You also should not have multiple elements with the same ID value.  Read this: http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/

So,

```
<a href="" class="extra extra_120" id="extra"></a>
<a href="" class="extra extra_145" id="extra"></a>
<a href="" class="extra extra_156" id="extra"></a>
```

should be

```
<a href="" class="extra extra_120" id="extra1"></a>
<a href="" class="extra extra_145" id="extra2"></a>
<a href="" class="extra extra_156" id="extra3"></a>
```

Comment: if i add id as  different you mentioned then what will be the selector.

Comment: Because multiple elements in a page can have the same class, you can use the class selector rather than the ID selector.  So $('a#extra') becomes $('a.extra') in the third line of the code from your question. See JQuery documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                         $(document).ready(function(){
                              $('.extralink').click(function(event){
                                 // alert($(this).attr('class'));
                                if($(this).attr('class') == 'extra'){
                                    event.preventDefault();
                                    $(this).append('<div style="float:left;color:red;margin-left:10px;font:20px;margin: 3px 0 0 10px;">Please Login/Register to view Details</div>').slideToggle(5000);
                                    window.location.href='http://weddingsinwinnipeg.ca/signin/';
                                }
                             });
                         });
                     </script>

<a href="" class="extra extra_120 extralink " ></a>
<a href="" class="extra extra_145 extralink " "></a>
<a href="" class="extra extra_156 extralink " ></a>
```

I think this is what you are looking for. Let me know if I understood your question wrong. The solution i think is to park link with "extra" class with another class like "extralink"

Comment: i have extra class which comes dynamically if user is not login, now when user clicks on an <a> checks if that anchor having that class then redirects to login page by appending a message to <a>, but there are multiple anchors present on the page, so each <a> element will have class extra.

Comment: is the extra class only belongs to anchor <a>? if so then just use .extra selector without adding another class. Is that so? $('.extra'). why this will not work?what am i missing ?